# Regex pattern matching for this, that or the other

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, pattern-matching

I have a problem I am trying to wrap my head around:

With a text string that can be any of the following variations, what steps should I take to pull out the information I require?

1. P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087-315-802-105-99
2. P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087-315-802-105
3. P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087-315-802
4. P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087-315
5. P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087

I need to return the values right of the -L- part of the string.

I already have the following pattern:

```
(\w{1}\d{5,}-\d{1,}-\w{2,}\d{2,}-\d{3,}-\w-)(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})|(\w{1}\d{5,}-\d{1,}-\w{2,}\d{2,}-\d{3,}-\w-)(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})|(\w{1}\d{5,}-\d{1,}-\w{2,}\d{2,}-\d{3,}-\w-)(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})|(\w{1}\d{5,}-\d{1,}-\w{2,}\d{2,}-\d{3,}-\w-)(\d{1,})-(\d{1,})|(\w{1}\d{5,}-\d{1,}-\w{2,}\d{2,}-\d{3,}-\w-)(\d{1,})
```

Thinking about it as I type this could I simply check which group number(s) the above pattern returns and then treat those group values as `group(1), group(2), group(n)` etc?

Comment: These are separate strings, right? And the regex you have "eats" them all up as 1 string. Do you just need [`-L-(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bP7dU3/1) and get Group 1 value?

Comment: Do you also need to find the strings that match any of these patterns into a big text or list of strings? Or all the strings you process match one of these formats and all you need is to identify the pieces?

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous, you can remove it; it only clutters the `regex`; `{1,}` is the same as `+` (if the language or tool you are using supports it); using `+` instead makes the `regex` more readable

Comment: Where are you using the regex? What is the tool/programming language?

Comment: @stribizhev: VB.NET is the language, Visual Studio Express 2015 is the IDE - and yes, they are separate strings.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, there is no point in using a regex for this:

```
Dim str20 As String = "P09876-01-TP02-005-L-1087-315-802-105-99"
Dim idx20 As Integer = str20.LastIndexOf("-L-")
Dim result20 As String = str20
If idx20 > -1 Then
   result20 = str20.Substring(idx20 + 3)
   Dim splts = result20.Split("-"c)
End If
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I do need to break up the groups of numbers that follow the -L- part of the string as I replied to @ClasG below

Comment: Split the found match with `-`: `splts` contain 5 elements that you can use to initialize whatever class you have.

Comment: That's excellent @stribizhev, thanks. Suppose I have another variation which doesn't have the -L- such as: P09876-01-TP04-003-220 wherein I need to split everything after the TP04-003 part of the string, what then?

Comment: How come you know it is after `TP04-003`? What is the actual specifications/requirements? Anyway, in this case you have a `-` separated string. Use `Split` and then analyze the number of elements in the resulting array and base further assignment on that number I guess, and perhaps, if input contains `-L`, too. `If str20.Contains("-L-") Then // proceed as above Else // just use Split End If`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the L-value, you only need to get `-L-(\d+)`. It gets the numeric value following the -L- as group 1. Or if the L-value is everything following the -L-, as stribizhev said `-L-(.*)`.

Edit: To get all the following as groups, try `-L-(\d+)(-\d*)?(-\d*)?(-\d*)?(-\d*)`. That'll get you all the following numbers as group 1, 2, 3...

Regards

Comment: when I get a match from one of the this or that patterns I then need to grab the groups that follow - if I take item one in my list above as an example, it breaks down into {Projectinfo}-{PartNum-Family}-{L-or-R}-{DimensionA}-{DimensionB}-{DimensionC}-{DimensionD}

Comment: @AlexF1980 - see Edit.

Comment: Due to optional `(-\d*)?`s the groups will be all messed up. I think a regex is not a good approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure on what the origin is in which you are searching. I understand you are looking for the values that come after the "L". But do all the strings follow this format? Assuming using that is so then using purely RegExp you could do something like:

```
[^L\n]+L-(\d+)-?(\d+)?-(\d+)?-(\d+)?-(\d+)?
```

Where the first part covers everything before the "L", excluding a new line. The parts after the first number series is optional (hence the "?").

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is my eventual solution to this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the dimension value from the part number
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PartNumString">the part number to search</param>
''' <param name="GroupNum"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks>This actually needs to do two things, one is to decide what the pattern is dependant on the Dimension we are searching for, the second is to find the correct group from the matches</remarks>
Private Function GetDimensionValueFromPartName(PartNumString As String, GroupNum As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim pattern As String = "(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)|(\w*\d*-\d*-\w*\d*-\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-)(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)-(\d*)|.*(\w*\d*-\d*-\w-)(\d*)"
    Dim Dimensionregex As Regex = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim match As Match = Dimensionregex.Match(PartNumString)
    Dim matchcount As Integer = 0
    Do While match.Success
        matchcount += 1
        Console.WriteLine("Match" & matchcount)
        Dim MatchStart As Integer = 0
        For index = 0 To match.Groups.Count
            If Not match.Groups(index).Value.Contains(PartNumString) And Not match.Groups(index).Value = String.Empty Then
                MatchStart = index
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not match.Groups(MatchStart + GroupNum).Value = String.Empty Then
            result = match.Groups(MatchStart + GroupNum).Value
        Else
            result = "-"
        End If

        match = match.NextMatch()
    Loop
    Return result
End Function
```

Suggestions or improvements gratefully received. (Yes, the pattern is horrendously long right now!)